# Issues loading assets for SlickGrid in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, slickgrid

I'm trying to use [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid) in a Rails 4 application and having a problem with getting some of the SlickGrid assets to load up properly.

Initially, I tried to use the [SlickGrid-Rails](https://github.com/liquidm/slickgrid-rails) gem, which loads the SlickGrid stuff into the Assets pipeline for you.  However, it turns out that the gem isn't compatible with Rails 4 at this time.

So I went and downloaded the SlickGrid source and began manually placing the files in my app.  Below is the setup I've performed.

**My File Setup**

- Placed all of the JavaScript files into vendor/assets/javascripts
- Placed all of the CSS files into vendor/assets/stylesheets
- Placed all of the image files (.gif, .png, etc) in assets/images.

---

**Assets Setup**

In my application.js file, I added the line ::

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts
```

In my application.css file, I added the line ::

```
*= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets
```

In my application.rb file, I added the line ::

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)
```

---

**Building the SlickGrid**

In my view file I have a single element ::

```
#my-slick-grid
```

---

**My JavaScript file**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var rows = [
                {
                    field_1: "value1",
                    field_2: "value2"
                }, {
                    field_1: "value3",
                    field_2: "value4"
                }
            ];

var columns = [
                {
                    name: "Address",
                    field: "address",
                    id: "address",  
                    sortable: true
                }, 
                {
                    name: "Rating, in %",
                    field: "rating", 
                    id: "rating_percent",
                    resizable: false
                }
            ];

var options = [];


var slickgrid = new Slick.Grid($("#my-slick-grid"), rows, columns, options);
});
```

---

**The Results**

When the view loads, I get "most" of the table, but it's not complete.
[image]

---

**The Errors**

Also, when I view the Chrome Console, I see the 2 following errors ::

```
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/images/header-columns-bg.gif 404 (Not Found)
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/images/ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6_1x400.png 404 (Not Found)
```

---

So, obviously Rails is having a problem either loading or knowing where to get the image files from.  Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?  I suspect that perhaps I'm not placing the SlickGrid files in the appropriate locations.  Perhaps someone can see what I'm doing wrong and correct me?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out.

I had to place all the SlickGrid image files into the public dir of my app.

Then I had to add the .scss extension onto each of the SlickGrid .css files.

Then, inside all of the SlickGrid .css.scss files, I had to replace all the

```
url('/assets/images/blahblah.gif')
```

with

```
url(asset-path('blahblah.gif'))
```

Now when I run the application, the table is fully drawn and there are no more 404 errors.